# How to convert csv into parquet file inside of HDFS

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I'm novice in `Big Data`, so `Hadoop` and `hdfs` is a bit vanished for me now, so I ask for help.
Now I have 4 files in `csv` format which located in `HDFS` cluster, and I should make 4 copies of them in `PARQUET` format using `Python`, and I haven't any idea how can I make it.
I hope you can help me with this not diffucult issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add what you have tried so far and where specifically you are stuck! We are not here to solve your task but to solve one specific problem!

Answer (score 0):

I put your example in `Scala` code, but doing it in `Python` is almost the same.

I put some comments too with some explanations

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ReadCsv {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("ReadCsv")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id","ReadCsv") // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    try {

      val df = sqlContext
        .read
        .csv("/path/directory_to_csv_files/") // Here we read the .csv files
        .cache()
      
      df.repartition(4) // we get four files
          .write
          .parquet("/path/directory_to_parquet_files/") // output format file.parquet.snappy by default
      // if we want parquet uncompressed before write we have to do:
      // sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "uncompressed")

      // To have the opportunity to view the web console of Spark: http://localhost:4040/
      println("Type whatever to the console to exit......")
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    } finally {
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped")
    }
  }
}
```